# Como recuperar o resultado de retorno de uma rotina de dentro de uma Thread?

Tags: java, android, thread

Preciso executar uma rotina dentro de uma Thread, e obter o retorno deste método. Meu código está deste jeito.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String resultado = "";
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run(){
                //varios processamentos
                String strDeRetorno = "abcde";///
                //???? Como retornar esse valor ao final da execucao??
            }
        };
        //Como recuperar o valor retornado pelo método run da Thread??
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Notem que não é caso de declarar algum tipo de variável global e alterá-la, até por que não existem "variáveis globais" em java. Quero realmente obter o valor de retorno da rotina, quando esta terminar.

Comment: A única forma que conheço é com gravação na Base de Dados.

Comment: Como assim? Seja mais especifico e dê um exemplo do que quer fazer.

Comment: Primeiro que nao existe essa tal coisa chamada "variavel global". Na verdade falamos de "Shared Data". Dados compartilhados entre múltiplas Threads. Provavelmente vc está se referindo a variáveis públicas e estáticas. Tente melhorar sua pergunta, o que vc está fazendo, o que vc não entende? O que vc quer dizer com "nao funcionam"?

Comment: Você pode detalhar melhor porque você afirma que não funcionam? Não funcionam em que sentido? Estou pensando em responder essa pergunta, mas tenho muita incerteza se a resposta que vou escrever vai servir. Estava pensando em falar sobre o modificador `volatile`, variáveis *effectively final*, variáveis locais vs de instância vs estáticas... Mas será que o que você quer realmente é isso?

Comment: Ola @daniel12345smith, vou responder a sua pergunta por aqui, ou seja, responder como resposta desta pergunta, pois a outra foi bloqueada. Acho qe entendi seu objetivo: retornar o valor de resultado da execucão da Thread.

Comment: Acabei de editar sua pergunta, assim que aprovarem eu respondo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Fui eu mesmo que escrevi o código da pergunta do autor, eu que escrevi este código errado ai, rs. Se possível, corrigir, ou me deixa corrigir. Obrigado.

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado pelas dicas @GuilhermeNascimento
Deixarem mais detalhado, nesse caso específico, esse código todo eu que escrevi, portanto acho que seria interessante eu mesmo editá-lo, não o autor, até por que reformulei a pergunta dele. Em fim, mais uma vez obrigado.

Comment: @FilipeGonzagaMiranda editado, boa noite.

Comment: @daniel12345smith , a pergunta está de acordo com a sua dúvida inicial?

Answer (score 6):

Essa funcionalidade é atingida através do uso de pools de Threads, disponíveis em Java, a partir, da versão 1.5, no [Executors Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html)

Ao invés de criar uma ***`Thread`***, você cria um *Pool com uma Thread*, e submete a ele as tarefas que quer que esta Thread execute. Para isso sua rotina deve implementar um `Callable<T>`. Esta é uam simples interface, que tem um método `call`, o equivalente ao `run` que você implementaria em uma Thread comum, só que com uma sutil e poderosa diferença: Ele permite que você retorno um valor de um tipo.

```
V call() throws Exception;
```

**Vamos ao código:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String resultado = "";

        //Criando um pool de Threads com uma Thread, 
        //equivalente ao sua Thread
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        //ao inves de chamarmos o metodo Thread.start(), chamamos:
        //executor.submit -> o que já permitirá que você obtenha um envólucro para
        //o resultado
        Future<String> futureResult = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {

            //Note como este não é um Runnable, e sim um Callable("primo" do Runnable)
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                String retorno = "";
                //processando
                //sua lógica
                // e assim por diante
                retorno = "abcde";
                return retorno;
            }
        });

        //Obtendo um resultado da execucão da Thread
        resultado = futureResult.get();

        System.out.println(resultado);

        //lembrar de chamar o shutodown no executor - para encerrar a
        //execucão
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

No momento que você submeter sua rotina, o método `ExecutorService.submit` te dará um `Future`

Este objeto Future vai te dar acesso ao valor de retorno deste callable que foi executado pela sua Thread. Isto se dará pela chamada do método `Future.get()`

Lembre-se de chamar: `executor.shutdown` - isto encerrará o Pool, o que tb impedirá novas tarefas de serem executadas.

> *Por favor leia também os comentários no código do exemplo. Devem te ajudar a entender o que está acontecendo.

Answer (score 1):

A variável é global, mas não poderá ser acessada por Thread's diferentes ao mesmo tempo. Para isto acontecer, a variável global deve ser declarada como **volatile**.
Para passar parâmetros de uma Thread a outra, usa-se  Observer e Observable
Segue: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html 
Segue um exemplo de implementação:

```
public class Observador implements Observer
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        final Observador main = new Observador();
        final Thread thread = new Thread(new Observado(main));
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) 
    {
        if(arg != null){
            System.out.println(arg);
        }
    }

    public static class Observado extends Observable implements Runnable
    {
        /**
         * Recebe quem irá receber as notificações....
         * @param o
         */
        public Observado(final Observer o) 
        {
            addObserver(o);
        }
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            int pt = 0;
            while(pt != 5){
                final Random random  = new Random();
                // gera um numero aleatorio 
                final Integer num =  random.nextInt();
                setChanged();
                //envia ao observador 
                notifyObservers(num);
                pt++;
            }

        }
    }
}
```